# How to rewrite puppeteer request header in case sensitive?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I try to rewrite the Header below:

```
await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
  "Accept-Language": "en-US;q=0.7",
});
```

However, when I inspect the network in Chrome, the request header is `accept-language` instead.

I expect it to be `Accept-Language`.

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Headers are case-insensitive. So should its handling also be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to work around with interception of the request like below:

```js
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on("request", request => {
  // Override headers
  const headers = Object.assign({}, request.headers(), {
    "Accept-Language": "en-US;q=0.7",
  });
  request.continue({ headers });
});
```